# Codility Problem: Frog Jump using C# (Cannot make it 100/100)

Tags: c#, algorithm

**PROBLEM**

A small frog wants to get to the other side of a river. The frog is initially located on one bank of the river (position 0) and wants to get to the opposite bank (position X+1). Leaves fall from a tree onto the surface of the river.

You are given an array A consisting of N integers representing the falling leaves. A[K] represents the position where one leaf falls at time K, measured in seconds.

The goal is to find the earliest time when the frog can jump to the other side of the river. The frog can cross only when leaves appear at every position across the river from 1 to X (that is, we want to find the earliest moment when all the positions from 1 to X are covered by leaves). You may assume that the speed of the current in the river is negligibly small, i.e. the leaves do not change their positions once they fall in the river.

```
For example, you are given integer X = 5 and array A such that:

  A[0] = 1
  A[1] = 3
  A[2] = 1
  A[3] = 4
  A[4] = 2
  A[5] = 3
  A[6] = 5
  A[7] = 4
```

In second 6, a leaf falls into position 5. This is the earliest time when leaves appear in every position across the river.

Write a function:

```
class Solution { public int solution(int X, int[] A); }
```

that, given a non-empty array A consisting of N integers and integer X, returns the earliest time when the frog can jump to the other side of the river.

If the frog is never able to jump to the other side of the river, the function should return −1.

```
For example, given X = 5 and array A such that:

  A[0] = 1
  A[1] = 3
  A[2] = 1
  A[3] = 4
  A[4] = 2
  A[5] = 3
  A[6] = 5
  A[7] = 4
```

the function should return 6, as explained above.

Write an efficient algorithm for the following assumptions:

N and X are integers within the range [1..100,000];
each element of array A is an integer within the range [1..X].

Copyright 2009–2021 by Codility Limited. All Rights Reserved. Unauthorized copying, publication or disclosure prohibited.

**QUESTION**

Why is my code not getting a 100/100 solution score?

**My Code for the Problem**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Solution {
    public int solution(int X, int[] A) {
        if(A.Length > 0){
            if(A.Contains(X)){
                return Array.IndexOf(A,X);
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you need to find the index in `A` where all the numbers from 1 to X have appeared at least once in a smaller index.  Basically your solution fails if a leaf at position 1 to X-1 falls after the leaf at position X.  Example X = 3 A = {2, 3, 1}, in that case all the leaves you need to cross have not fallen until time 2, but your solution would return 1.

Comment: Your solution doesn't account for the fact that there needs to be leaves in the previous positions up to X (e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4). For example, With X as 2, you could have A equal to be simply {2}, but that should fail as there's no 1 in A.

Comment: Ohhh, Now i get it. My understanding on the problem was wrong from the start. Thank you so much for answering.

Comment: FYI probably the best way to solve this is to create a HashSet of all the values from 1-X and Remove them as you move through the array and once it's empty you've found the answer.  Or just add values <= X to a HashSet until it contains X values.